Why is the increment list unbound?
I am trying to run a subexperiment and I am running into a strange error. The number of subexepriments seems to be limited. This works:
["gender" "male"]
["swimmingStyle" "free"]
["poolLength" 50]
["simulationDuration" 1]
["numberLanesPool2" 0]
["lengthOfPool2" 25]
["carefulAtWall" false]
["patiencePercentage" 100]
["allocation" "logic" "random" "clustering"]
[["numberOfLanes" 1] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [4 1 50]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 2] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [8 1 100]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 3] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [12 1 150]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 4] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [16 1 200]]]

But if I add just a few more lines I get an error message:
["gender" "male"]
["swimmingStyle" "free"]
["poolLength" 50]
["simulationDuration" 1]
["numberLanesPool2" 0]
["lengthOfPool2" 25]
["carefulAtWall" false]
["patiencePercentage" 100]
["allocation" "logic" "random" "clustering"]
[["numberOfLanes" 1] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [4 1 50]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 2] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [8 1 100]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 3] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [12 1 150]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 4] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [16 1 200]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 5] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [20 1 250]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 6] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [24 1 300]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 7] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [28 1 350]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 8] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [32 1 400]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 9] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [36 1 450]]]
[["numberOfLanes" 10] ["numberSwimmersInPool" [40 1 500]]]

The error is:
The following values are invalid: 
Variable: Increment list "["numberSwimmersInPool" [ 20.0 1.0 250.0 ]]" is unbounded, reverse sign of step value

I also tried to only use the last four entries, and that works. What could be the problem?
